# YII 2 REST CORS issue on remote server

Tags: ajax, rest, yii2, cors, basic-authentication

I have developed a Yii2 REST API application. Everything is working fine in local.
I have deployed the application to remote server. I could get api responses via Postman. But when i try to make a request with AJAX or Angular I get "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401" error.
my Controller behaviors() method:

```
public function behaviors() {

    return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [


        $behaviors['corsFilter']  = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors'  => [
                // restrict access to domains:
                'Origin'                           => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE','OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,                 // Cache (seconds)
            ],
        ],
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => AvnrHttpBasicAuth::className(),
        ],

    ]);
}
```

Response and Request Headers:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I assume this is CORS issue but i cannot figure out why this is not working on the remote server running on Centos with apache.

I have extended HttpBasicAuth and using my own AvnrHttpBasicAuth class

```
class AvnrHttpBasicAuth extends HttpBasicAuth
{
    public function authenticate($user, $request, $response)
    {

        $authHeader = $request->getHeaders()->get('Authorization');

        if ($authHeader !== null && preg_match("/^Basic\\s+(.*?)$/", $authHeader, $matches)) {

            $identity = $user->loginByAccessToken($matches[1], get_class($this));

            if ($identity === null) {
                $this->handleFailure($response);
            }
            return $identity;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue with a minor modification to my .htaccess file.
Thanks to this [post](https://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/)

these two lines below in .htaccess file did the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: This will allow requests from any origin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an exception for preflight requests as shown in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#cors):

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
    'class' => AvnrHttpBasicAuth::className(),
    'except' => ['options']
],
```

[Preflight Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) are handled/issued by browser when needed. like when frontend and backend are hosted in different domains and you are making a POST request as example, browser need to send an OPTIONS request first to see if POST is allowed before sending the real one. To test it from POSTMAN you need to send an OPTIONS request instead of POST/PUT.

Comment: I added 'except' => ['options'] exception but still the same.

Comment: How ever http://XXX.XXX.73.161/~dsltrading/v1/web/api/customer/view?id=1 returns : 405 "Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET, HEAD

Comment: I assumed that `AvnrHttpBasicAuth` has an `except` property as all of Yii2 official filters. But it may not have it. I don't know what library is that.

Comment: what controller are you extending? is it ActiveController? and what server is that? if IIS I think you need to config it to allow those verbs

Comment: I am extending ApiController (my own controller) where ApiController Extended from ActiveController
I have modified my question and added my AvnrHttpBasicAuth Class.

Comment: ActiveController has [this action](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/85294ab4e3d03b648a5ed97858a16d5744e9d69b/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L102) to respond to preflight requests. Its implementation is [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/85294ab4e3d03b648a5ed97858a16d5744e9d69b/framework/rest/OptionsAction.php#L20). Not sure why in your case it responds with only GET and  HEAD verbs. [default implementation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/85294ab4e3d03b648a5ed97858a16d5744e9d69b/framework/rest/OptionsAction.php#L29) should return them all.

Comment: Salem thank for your answers. the default implementation didn't work form  me. The default implementation did not pick up my Basic auth token. thats why i had to implement the following in my own Auth class and check for the token as follow :
if ($authHeader !== null && preg_match("/^Basic\\s+(.*?)$/", $authHeader, $matches)) {
would you be able to take a look at my code ? I would really apreciate.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me so far. If by adding `'except' => ['options']` your are getting `405 "Method Not Allowed"` instead of `401` then the authenticator works fine as it has been skipped on OPTIONS request. Use POSTMAN to see what your server responds to OPTIONS request. if as you said, it says only GET and HEAD are allowed then probably the issue is either from the OptionsAction returning different values from what I linked above or your server need to be configured to accept OPTIONS verbs.